# Как удалить перенос строки по условию в bat файле

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bat

Коллеги, приветствую!
Есть текстовый файл со строками вида:

```
00:00.741004-1,DBMSSQL,5,p:processName=QQQ,t:computerName=SRV,t:connectID=144493,Usr=Расписание,dbpid=66,Sql='INSERT INTO dbo._InfoRg43436 (_Fld43437RRef,_Fld43438,_Fld43439) VALUES(?,?,?)',Context='
МодульСеанса : 7 : ПолныеПрава.УстановитьПараметрыМеханизмаОграниченияПравДоступа();
    ОбщийМодуль.ПолныеПрава.Модуль : 710 : Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ТекущийПользователь", Пользователи.АвторизованныйПользователь());
        ОбщийМодуль.Пользователи.Модуль : 15 : Возврат ПользователиКлиентСервер.АвторизованныйПользователь();
            ОбщийМодуль.ПользователиКлиентСервер.Модуль : 22 : Возврат ПараметрыСеанса.ТекущийПользователь;
00:01.148006-1,DBMSSQL,5,p:processName=QQQ,t:computerName=SR,t:connectID=144494,Usr=Расписание189,dbpid=66,Sql='DELETE FROM T1
FROM dbo._InfoRg43436 T1
WHERE T1._Fld43437RRef = ? AND T1._Fld43438 = ? AND T1._Fld43439 = ?
p_0: 0xA9A4F8F21E2B439D11EAA92A9F1C4FDE
p_1: 5673N
p_2: 40200608130000
',Context='
МодульСеанса : 7 : ПолныеПрава.УстановитьПараметрыМеханизмаОграниченияПравДоступа();'
```

Необходимо сделать так, что если строка начинается по шаблону рег. выражения \d\d:\d\d.\d+- то строки стоящие после нее и не подходящие под этот шаблон должны переносится на эту строку с определенным разделителем, например таким "|".
Или если перефразировать, если строка не подходит под регулярку, то перенести ее на предыдущую строку поставив перед ней символ "|".
В моем примере должно получиться следующее:

```
00:00.741004-1,DBMSSQL,5,p:processName=QQQ,t:computerName=SRV,t:connectID=144493,Usr=Расписание,dbpid=66,Sql='INSERT INTO dbo._InfoRg43436 (_Fld43437RRef,_Fld43438,_Fld43439) VALUES(?,?,?)',Context='|МодульСеанса : 7 : ПолныеПрава.УстановитьПараметрыМеханизмаОграниченияПравДоступа();|   ОбщийМодуль.ПолныеПрава.Модуль : 710 : Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("ТекущийПользователь", Пользователи.АвторизованныйПользователь());|        ОбщийМодуль.Пользователи.Модуль : 15 : Возврат ПользователиКлиентСервер.АвторизованныйПользователь();|          ОбщийМодуль.ПользователиКлиентСервер.Модуль : 22 : Возврат ПараметрыСеанса.ТекущийПользователь;'
00:01.148006-1,DBMSSQL,5,p:processName=QQQ,t:computerName=SR,t:connectID=144494,Usr=Расписание189,dbpid=66,Sql='DELETE FROM T1|FROM dbo._InfoRg43436 T1|WHERE T1._Fld43437RRef = ? AND T1._Fld43438 = ? AND T1._Fld43439 = ?|p_0: 0xA9A4F8F21E2B439D11EAA92A9F1C4FDE|p_1: 5673N|p_2: 40200608130000|',Context='|МодульСеанса : 7 : ПолныеПрава.УстановитьПараметрыМеханизмаОграниченияПравДоступа();'
```

Comment: Регулярные выражения? в батче? серьёзно? слушайте, ну не занимайтесь фигнёй, напишите простенький скриптик на VBS, который всё это сделает практически единым махом... один join() и один regexp.replace.

Comment: Буду премного благодарен если приведете пример такого скрипта.

Comment: [JOIN function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//yscc53h0(v=vs.85)). [RegExp.Replace method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//k9z80300(v=vs.85)). Примеры там есть.

Comment: Все равно не очень понятно как из этих кирпичей собрать именно то, что мне требуется.

Answer (score 0):

### [ join.vbs ]

```vbs
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2    
Const SourceFileName = "c:\tmp\src.txt"
Const DestinationFileName = "c:\tmp\dst.txt"
Const Pattern = "\|(\d\d:\d\d.\d+-)"
Const Replacement = vbNewLine & "$1"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set regEx = New RegExp

Set SRCfile = fso.OpenTextFile(SourceFileName, ForReading)
Set DSTfile = fso.OpenTextFile(DestinationFileName, ForWriting, True)

regEx.Pattern = Pattern

DSTfile.Write regEx.Replace(Replace(SRCfile.ReadAll, vbNewLine, "|"), Replacement)

SRCfile.Close
DSTfile.Close
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но при запуске возникает ошибка Строка 5 Символ 37. Непонятно что за переменная vbNewLine

Comment: @andreynikus А ты как его выполняешь-то? vbNewLine - предопределённая константа, интерпретатор её не может не знать.

Comment: Сохранил файл с расширением vbs, и выполняю через командную строку. Пишет что предпологается наличие текстовой константы литерала

Comment: @andreynikus Не могу у себя воспроизвести подобную хрень... ну попробуй определить как `Const vbNewLine = CHR(13) & CHR(10)`, что ли...

Comment: [Вот изображение ошибки](https://ibb.co/hVLj1mg)

Comment: То же самое, только теперь на символ 45 ругается, ему как - будто "$1" не нравиться.

Comment: Проверяй систему. Что-то у тебя неладно с интерпретатором VBScript...

Comment: Сделал так DSTfile.Write regEx.Replace(Replace(SRCfile.ReadAll, vbCr & vbLf, "|"), vbNewLine & "$1")   
Вроде заработало, но не так как нужно. У меня весь файл в 2 строки ужался ))

Comment: *заработало, но не так как нужно. У меня весь файл в 2 строки ужался* В тексте вопроса я вижу исходные данные, которые, согласно описанию, обязаны дать в итоге две строки. И в желаемом ответе я вижу тоже две строки. И что, собственно, не так?

Comment: Просто в описании я привел лишь 2 строки для примера, в файле их сотни тысяч таких строк. Можно ли доработать скрипт в соответствии с этим?

Comment: @andreynikus SO - вообще-то QA. На нём даже такие ответы, как мой, не очень-то комильфо (да и такие вопросы, как Ваш, по большому счёту). А уж отлаживать ЗДЕСЬ... за Вас... пока Вы, сложа ручки, ждёте готовенького... Извините, но обратитесь на любой программистский форум (хобот, виноград, сырцы, вэбэстритс и пр.) - возможно, там кому-то будет в радость возиться с отладкой ВМЕСТО ВАС.

Comment: да проблема не в лени, проблема в том что я не программист vbs даже близко ))

Comment: для отладки нужно хотя бы знать этот язык -)
Ладно, спасибо что помогли, пойду курить форумы

Answer (score 0):

В итоге навоял следующее

```
Const SourceFileName = "c:\1\1\20060813.log"
Const DestinationFileName = "c:\1\1\20060813_4.log"
Const Pattern = "^\d\d:\d\d.\d"
Set regEx = New RegExp

regEx.Pattern = Pattern
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
objStream.Type = 2
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile SourceFileName

Set objStream2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream2.Charset = "utf-8"
objStream2.Type = 2
objStream2.Open

str0 = ""
Do Until objStream.EOS
    str1 = objStream.ReadText(-2)
    if regEx.Test(str1) then 
        objStream2.WriteText str0, 1
        str0 = str1
        else
        str0 = str0 & "|" & str1 
    end if
Loop

if str0 <> str1 then objStream2.WriteText str0, 1

objStream2.SaveToFile DestinationFileName

objStream.Close
objStream2.Close
```